# What is the name of SharedPreferences file name?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I am new to Android and I am kind of stuck for 6 hours straight.

The problem is I don't know the name of the preferences file, and I need to get values from preferences file. I am using Android Studio and created a "Settings Activity". All the way I had not given name to any file except `SettingsActivity.java`.

So my question is what is the name of the Shared Preferences file (cause the application is keeping the values). Or otherwise if there is a way to find out.

Or perhaps I am missing something obvious in code. Following is my relevant code.

```
String key = "example_text";
final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "SettingsActivity";
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = preferences.getString(key, " null");
```

**EDIT 1**: I have an activity named `RemoteDevice.java`, within this activity I have a Async Task subclass for internet usage. Now I have stored IP address through the above mentioned PreferencesActivity and now want to retrieve it. But am unable to find it.

**EDIT 2:** In the following code I am trying to get value from edit text.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference accepts EditText attributes. -->
<!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="example_text"
    android:title="@string/pref_host_ip_address"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_host_address"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="123456789."
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<!-- NOTE: Hide buttons to simplify the UI. Users can touch outside the dialog to
     dismiss it. -->
<!-- NOTE: ListPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
<ListPreference
    android:key="example_list"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_add_friends_to_messages"
    android:defaultValue="-1"
    android:entries="@array/pref_example_list_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_example_list_values"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null" />
```

And  I am guessing here `android:key` is the key to be passed as arguments in

> String value = preferences.getString(key, " null");

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I am using Android Studio and created a "Settings Activity".

Then you get your `SharedPreferences` via `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`. Replace:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Comment: I already tried that but the problem is I am using the above mentioned code in an AsyncTask-SubClass of another activity.

Comment: @AbbasA.Ali: So? That does not change how you access the `SharedPreferences` instance used by `PreferenceFragment` and `PreferenceActivity`. You call `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, supplying as a parameter *any* `Context` from your app (e.g., an instance of an `Activity`).

Comment: So u can give any context of any activity in any activity?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I am still getting `null`.

Comment: thanks I got it by using your method. I apologize for late response but a few of my friends advised me against rooting my device. But in the end it worked for me and I found the file. Moreover is there a way to change the name of Shared Pref. file? Or change the name at build time? Thanks.

Comment: This way is Deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
String key = "example_text";
final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "SettingsActivity";
shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = preferences.getString(key, " null");
```

But first you have to save some value with your key like:

```
shared.edit().putString(key,"MY_VALUE").commit();
```

Comment: I am using my android phone for this, and it retains the changed values. So I think the values are there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: make your question clear, what is the issue you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Run your project on a real device and if a SharedPreferences file (it has .xml extension) is created you can find it in the root catalog of the device, here to be more exact:

/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml
or 
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml

By the way, you may just use getPreferences() method. Change your

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

into

SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

Your SharedPreferences file will get a default name. But keep in mind that it is worth using getPreferences() instead of getSharedPreferences() only if you won't need more than one SharedPreferences file in your project.

Comment: I am running it on my android phone. But where is data folder?

Comment: I don't see my project's package name. Does that mean there is no preference's file? Cause whenever I run the app and change preferences on my phone and re-run it, it stays updated. Also tried 'Show Hidden Files and Folders'

Comment: May be your app is installed at the external SD. Did you check there?

Comment: That's the problem I don't have an external SD.

Comment: You need to get to your file system root. If it is not possible from your file browser try Total Commander for Android.